# How do I ensure my pdf-generating application supports as many language fonts as possible?

Tags: pdf, fonts, internationalization, pdf-generation

I am developing an application that generates a PDF based on user input. One of the user inputs is a foreign postal address in the native script of that country, which could possibly be anything.  I know I can't support all possible glyphs, but I want to cover as much as reasonably possible. My plan right now is to:

1. Find a 'default' font that handles the easier languages (left-to-right langs with few glyphs like most latin alphabets, cyrillic, greek). I am thinking Ubuntu Font because it has a very liberal license
2. Find a fonts for common languages/language sets like CJK, arabic.
3. When I need to add text to a pdf, I try to find a font in my set that can handle all the codepoints in the string, starting with the default.

Does that sound like a reasonable thing to do, or is there an easier way? Is there a list of top N languages/writing systems I should be supporting?

I also wonder how web browsers do such a good job in displaying any language correctly (I haven't seen a 'tofu' character for unknown codepoint in a while.)

Comment: *"I try to find a font in my set that can handle all the codepoints in the string"* - why do you want to find a single font that handles all those code points? It may well happen that you have to use multiple fonts to handle the whole string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how big you application can be, you could take a look at [Noto](https://www.google.com/get/noto/), which  will "support all languages with a harmonious look and feel." But be warned that covering *every* writing system on the planet will require at least a gigabyte of fonts.

Browsers support a large range of writing systems ("languages") by relying on different fallback fonts supplied by the operating system. Only when they are exhausted you will see a tofu.

Answer (score 0):

> Does that sound like a reasonable thing to do, or is there an easier way?

Essentially items 1 and 2 together mean "collect enough fonts to cover a large enough portion of the Unicode code points". That obviously is necessary.

As @RoelN mentions in his answer, Noto might be a set of fonts to consider.

Item 3, though,

> When I need to add text to a pdf, I try to find a font in my set that can handle all the codepoints in the string, starting with the default.

does not make sense. Of course, if there is such a single font, you could use it. But what if there is not?

So I would propose not to count on the existence of such a font but instead split your string into substrings that each consists of characters covered by a single font from your list, and draw your full string piece-wise, changing the font between pieces.

Most likely you will not only have to split your string by font but also by direction (RTL vs. LTR), at least in an intermediate step.

> Is there a list of top N languages/writing systems I should be supporting?

Which language systems you *should* report, depends clearly on your use case. As you want *to cover as much as reasonably possible*, you probably should simply start with a font family like Noto and extend your list of fonts appropriately whenever your application logs a lookup failure for some character.